# Proper way to remove NaN

Tags: python, pandas

What is the suggested way to remove `NaN` values in pandas? I feel like this must be such a common thing/question, but yet it seems like the tools that are 'built-in' never seem to work for the cases I have, for example:

This works:

```
np.where(raw_df['deliveries'].str.lower().isin(('nan','none')), None, raw_df['deliveries'])
```

[image]

This does not:

```
raw_df['deliveries'] = np.where(raw_df['deliveries'].isna(), None, raw_df['deliveries'])
```

[image]

Why it doesn't work is beyond me (perhaps it only accepts a scalar-only column?), but I'm seeing what the least-hackish and most versatile way to deal with removing `NaN`s in a column seems to be?

Comment: If `isin('nan')` evaluates to true, you would have the actual string `ǹan` instead of NaN in your column. Have you tried setting `na_values` when reading the data?

Comment: you need to make an reproducible example. It's not clear if the "nans" are strings or proper NaN values. The pandas's tag wiki has good a link to a question explaining how best to do this

Comment: This `raw_df['deliveries'].str.lower().isin(('nan','none'))` is not the same as `raw_df['deliveries'].isna()`. The string `'nan'` is not `NaN` (that stands for not a number) and the string `none` is not the value `None`.

Comment: @PaulH how can I check which one it is? Also, the StackOverflow wiki or the Pandas one? Could you please provide a link?

Comment: The wiki for the pandas tag has the links you need https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pandas